# Scope custom fields to Site Collection or Site

Tags: 2010, custom-field-types, scope

Is there any way to scope a custom field to a particular site collection or site?

Answer (score 0):

Creation of a content type should fulfill what you're looking for. Creation of a content type can then be scoped all the way to list level. Alternatively, you could create a feature to be deployed, deploying at site or site collection level.